# How to map only my include list but not on my exclude list in BizTalk Mapping? But they share the same first input?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I would like to block certain message to not go through via mapping & scriptoid. But I would also like to only let in certain messages.

For instance, I would like to block someone with a First Name "John" concatenated with "Doe" so the result is "JohnDoe" but in my include list, I want the mapping to go through if the first name is "John".

So mapping like this:

if (First Name + Last Name) = "JohnDoe" ----> do not map to "Participant"

if (First Name) = "John" ---> Map to "Participant"

But I have a lot of names that needs to blocked so I can't just manually type JohnDoe. I'm instead using an excel spreadhsheet for names that I want to be blocked and filtering this through the send pipeline.

My problem is I can't find the logic to do this mapping. Right now, I'm using a scriptoid and calling the name of the spreadsheet I've created with all the blocked list of names. But it doesn't seem to be working. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not approach the solution in this way. It is probably asking for maintenance trouble to bury this kind of logic in Biztalk map.

I would look at refactoring it, and possibly re-point the right side of the map at a handler process (like a web service etc.) that handles the exclusion of names and then let that output the result message with the required data. Having the map load a spreadsheet of data isn't ideal.

If you must do it this way, you are going to have to supply some error messages and some specifics of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a scriptoid and calling the name of the spreadsheet

You definitely don't want to do that.  It's just very unoptimal design and difficult to support.

The Map should transform the data and the 'filter' should be applied at another step in the process, such as an Orchestration where you can use the Business Rules Engine to define the filter rules.